# How can I wall jump in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I Have been trying to get a wall-jumping system to work in unity but no matter what I do it does not work can anyone show me the code which will be able to do this with an explanation or tell me what I have to do for it to work?

I want the player to jump to the other wall whenever I press the jump button

I Am using the character controller for movement

```
void WallJump(){
        if (isWalled)
        {
            gravity = -1f;
            canDoubleJump = false;
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isWalled)
            {
                isWalled = false;
                direction.y = jumpForce;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code I am currently using which causes the player to be able to jump on the same wall every time they click and I have to manually rotate it towards the other wall to jump towards it

Comment: You probably have to implement the rotation into the jump then?

Comment: Well I tried adding this code for rotating the player when space is pressed and the player is on the wall but something like that will only rotate the player in one direction and it only rotates when space is pressed two times  
all i need to know really is how to prevent the player from being able to jump multiple times when the player is on the wall

`Quaternion flip = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(0,0,-180));
                transform.rotation = flip;`

@derHugo

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could take into account the direction in which the player is pretending to go through input and then set the direction.x equal to the direction the player is pressing. If it's none then it will go up the wall, otherwhise he will be launched up and in the direction the player is pressing. But remember to check if the direction he's pressing is against the wall or not.